Assessing whether a dataset follows a distribution using Q-Q Plot
I recently found myself answering a question on Stack Overflow about adjusting a dataset to a unknown distribution.
Adding my two cents to the community, I have provided a script to draw a Q-Q Plot in order to inspect the whole behaviour of the model against the dataset. Mainly the OP wants a model that preserves lower quantiles as close as possible to the model while the tail may take off.
I did few checks with known asymmetric laws and I kept the Weibull and Log Normal to compare their behaviour. What I see is that none of those law are valid to represent the complete dataset (we can add KS test to confirm it but it seems to me that Q-Q plot is sufficient to discriminate).
Anyway, some users, based on the histogram and standard statistics matching, think it is a Weibull distribution, while the Q-Q plot looks like:

To me it looks like an evidence that it is not a Weibull. Even worse, low quantiles will take off if using this model.
Am I right in my reasoning?
May I kindly ask the cross-validated community to peer review my answer on SO.

You're raising issues on different levels. 1. People wanting to join that thread on SO should do that directly. I am surprised that the thread is regarded as on-topic and won't join in myself with an answer. 2. IIUC the OP on SO has yet to provide access to their data and as someone rightly pointed out a good discussion of what works well for their data is not possible otherwise. 3. I agree that what you're showing is not well fitted by a Weibull but exact;y what you're doing needs more explanation and what would fit better is hard to say as I don't think you explain your "data" either.

Otherwise put: A. A question here should stand on its own two feet and not depend on an SO thread quite likely to disappear. B. But in any case questions about which distribution(s) fit data well seem natural here and not at all on SO and to me at least an answerable version of the SO thread would be welcome here.

It was you who pointed out that the data are needed, not "someone". Sorry about that detail. But when I say that what you're doing needs more explanation I mean more explanation here, as in the comment one up the principle is (A).

I receive all your information, thank you for that. We can clearly say I am not used to CV. Data have been provided by the user (in the comment).

FWIW, I strongly agree that K-S tests are fairly useless for this problem, and indeed almost always.

Thanks for that correction. The link is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UfMq4Ge0BAvggTekzAmsstTD3jxvnkynLwBTVCNgxmw/edit?pli=1&gid=834503224#gid=834503224
